# Share Extension not working with iOS 9

Tags: ios9, ios8-share-extension, ios9.1, share-extension

I have an issue with share extension,

1. Open the Mail App.
2. Select the mail with PDF attachment.
3. If I long press on the pdf then i showing up my app but I Open the PDF in documentinteractioncontroller and clicking on the share icon then I am not able to see my app.

Above steps are working fine with ios8 but only issue in the ios9 or later.

I need to open share extension from share icon of documentInteractionController.

Please help me as soon as possible...

Answer (score 2):

On iOS9 due to the new changes on Safari security you have to set what kind of URL would work with your Share extension, for example, showing your Share extension only for text, images, etc...

Maybe the problem could be that you have to set what kind of data your app accept from Share extensions. You can set this param on your extension plist adding values to the dictionary NSExtension - NSExtensionAttributes

[image]

There's a list with the types you can use there (like NSExtensionActivationSupportsWebURLWithMaxCount, NSExtensionActivationSupportsText, etc... Maybe you need NSExtensionActivationSupportsAttachmentsWithMaxCount):

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/SystemExtensionKeys.html

I hope it helps

Comment: I have tried this solutions but it won't works for me. After opening PDF from e-mail (which opens in documentInteractionController), at bottom part we have "share" icon. On tapping that share icon, I can not see my App in UIActivity Controller.

Comment: try to set NSExtensionActivationRule to TRUEPREDICATE, and if your extension shows from this point, you only need to pick the correct NSExtensionActivationRule for your purpose

Comment: My app is showing activity controller pop and also i am getting URL but app is not move main page.